# Is kd-Tree an alternative to K-means clustering?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, k-means, kdtree

I'm working with BOW object detection and I'm working on the encoding stage. I have seen some implementations that use `kd-Tree` in the encoding stage, but most writings suggest that `K-means` clustering is the way to go.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kd-tree` AFAIK is used for the labeling phase, its much faster, when clustering over a large number of groups, hundreds if not thousands, then the naive approach of simply taking the argmin of all the distances to each group, k-means `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering` is the actual clustering algorithm, its fast though not always very precise, some implementations return the groups, while others the groups and the labels of the training data set, this is what I ussually use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html in conjunction with http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2.html

Comment: so just to clarify, you would use kmeans to quantize your image descriptors. Then you would make a kdtree out of those descriptors so that you can search for the closest neighbor in object recognition?

Comment: @mugetsu `Then you would make a kdtree out of those descriptors` pretty much, I've done some benchmarks and well kdtree blows all my optimizations out of the water when working with really large number of groups ... I recommend you simply run some tests :)

Comment: so by using kdtree, do you skip having histograms and SVMs? I'm confused on how this works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091972/implementing-bags-of-words-object-recognition-using-vlfeat

Comment: @mugetsu check out http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs143/results/proj3/sungmin/ I couldn't find an easier tutorial ...

Comment: Updating above link: http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs143/2011/results/proj3/sungmin/

Answer (score 6):

In object detection, k-means is used to quantize descriptors. A kd-tree can be used to search for descriptors with or without quantization. Each approach has its pros and cons. Specifically, kd-trees are not much better than brute-force search when the number of descriptor dimensions exceeds 20.

Comment: i'm using SIFT descriptors, 128 dimensions, so I guess in my encoding phase I should only be quantizing with k-means?

Comment: I have had achieved great performance using just hierarchical k-means clustering with vocabulary trees and brute-force search at each level. If I needed to further improve performance, I would have looked into using either locality-sensitive hashing or kd-trees combined with dimensionality reduction via PCA.

Comment: I'm recommending on FLANN. It will do the analysis for you and give you the best algorithm that fits your specific data set and memory / performance needs. See http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN

Comment: @DonReba, I would like to do hierarchical k-means. What software did you use to do this?

Comment: @TyanTowers, just OpenCV for `k-means`. Did the rest myself in C++.

Answer (score 2):

`kd-Tree` and `K-means` algorithm are two different types of clustering method.

Here are several types of clustering method as follows:

- `kd-Tree` is a [hierarchical-clustering](/questions/tagged/hierarchical-clustering) method (median-based).
- `K-means` is a means-based clustering method.
- `GMM` (Gaussian mixture model) is a probability-based clustering method (soft-clustering).
- etc.

---

[UPDATE]:

<sub>Generally, there are two types of clustering method, soft clustering, and hard clustering. Probabilistic clustering like the GMM are soft clustering type with assigning objects to the clusters with probabilities, and others are hard clustering with assigning objects to a cluster absolutely.</sub>

Comment: There are many more clustering methods than these three. GMM is not really a clustering method, though I guess you could use it as such. K-means does not use standard deviation at all, it's based on means and Voronoi tessellation.

Comment: yes of course, there are many more clustering methods.
in kmeans, objects select by minimum standard deviation in each cluster with its computed means, so I mentioned standard deviation too.
and gmm could be as a clustering method, for example with three gaussian distributions which objects belong to each them with comparing their probabilty like the kmeans with three means.

Comment: I just questioned the usefulness of mentioning one other clustering algorithm when the question is "what is the difference between methods A and B", considering there exist so many clustering algorithms, and [there already exist lists that try to collect them all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cluster_analysis_algorithms).

Comment: Regarding k-means: objects are selected by minimum distance to each mean (as in Voronoi tessellation), not by standard deviation. The standard deviation is never computed or implied.

Comment: I didn't want to say the std-dev being calculated (I wrote incorrectly). My mean was that means calculated and in the obtained cluster, each object has minimum variance/std-dev across other objects.
[And this is about the GMM in O'Reilly book about unsupervised learning.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCoLd.png)